# div click event automatically getting fired on page load

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to create html page which has series of  ( e.g.div has list of employee details ).  When user click on div I want to navigate to another page.  Please have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3jXuA/3/).

Problem is click event of div is getting fired when I am loading page for the first time.
  How can I avoid unnecessary click events those are getting fired during page load event?

### Below is my html code

```
<div data-bind="click: clickMe('ok1')">
    <h1>Emplyee details</h1>
    <p>This is test</p>    
</div>

<div data-bind="click: clickMe('ok2')">
    <h1>Emplyee details</h1>
    <p>This is test</p>    
</div>

var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.clickMe = function(url){   
        //This function is automatically getting called 
        //when page loads.
        alert(url);
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Regards,
Hemant

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to pass a function to the click handler rather than the result of the click function.

Doing `clickMe()` fires the method and returns the result to the handler.

One way to do what you want is to wrap the function call in an anonymous function as so:

```
function(){ clickMe('params'); }
```

So you get:

```
<div data-bind="click: function(){ clickMe('ok1'); }">
```

Alternatively you can use the `bind` function on your `clickMe` method to pass the params you want:

```
clickMe.bind($data, "param1")
```

So you get:

```
<div data-bind="click: clickMe.bind($data, 'param1')">
```

Comment: You don't event need the method on the viewmodel, just do what you need in the anonymous function: `<div data-bind="click: function(){ alert('ok1'); }">` or `<div data-bind="click: function(){ alert($data.xxxxx()); }">`